# After forced restart hard drive not visible

Tags: dual-boot, freeze

I have dual boot Ubuntu 20.04/Windows10. Ubuntu freezes regularly and current only solution is to force restart (using pc case button). After restart pc goes to bios settings because it doesn't see hard drive (ssd). Then to make hard disk visible again these are steps I do:

1. I force shut down pc with pc case button
2. Then ssd is visible again but this time boot order is switched. Now windows 10 is booting first.
3. I restart once again to enter bios settings and make ubuntu bootable first
4. I try to boot ubuntu. Sometimes it's boot normally and sometimes it stuck on recovering journal.
5. If it's stuck on recovering journal I need to put bootable ubuntu usb, restart pc to enter boot live ubuntu usb and preform fsck on ubuntu partition. After that restart again and everything is normal again until next ubuntu freez.

Did anyone experience similar thing and does anyone have any solution to this cause it's starts to be very annoying?

Comment: You're forced to use power button?  Are you saying SysRq commands direct to the kernel (bypassing a locked GUI/desktop/session) don't work?, you can't switch to a text terminal etc.... As currently written, the issues read to me like they're user created because you're not mentioning any of the steps you use well before resorting to a power-off/pulling power cord....

Comment: @guiverc yes, i'm forced to use power button to fully shut down pc in order to make ssd visible to motherboard again

Comment: You should have specifically mentioned the SysRq commands not working, as that means either you've got a broken keyboard OR the kernel has frozen (assuming you're using a release of Ubuntu; you haven't given details, that has SysRq enabled)

Comment: @guiverc I'm sure that keyboard is not broken because it's working normally until freeze. I will check if SysRq functions are enabled so I can run it and be prepared for next freeze, thanks

Comment: You've provided no release details, but SysRq implies kernel issues to me, and thus switching from one stack to another may solve issues; eg. i have an old thinkpad on *bionic* that didn't like the 5.4 kernel, but by using the GA kernel the issue doesn't exist (my preference over using the older now-unsupported 5.3 kernel...)